# How to use porcelli/plsql-parser for .NET

Tags: .net, parsing, plsql

I am developing a custom tool to perform static code analysis for PL/SQL script file. For this purpose I need to parse the .sql file and need to visit each statements to check any coding violations.

I browsed on google and found PL/SQL parser from (https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser) but the source code contains .g extension files.

How to compile the source code and how to get .dll from the source code in-order to add the dll as a reference in my .NET project to use the parser.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: The .g extension signifies ANTLR files.  The ANTLR site offers tools for generating C# code from grammar files.  [Check it out](http://www.antlr.org/download.html)

Comment: there is no such examples on how to build .g files and to use in .NET. Please guide me.